# How to restrict multiple Email IDs to insert into the database?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, jdbc

When a user registers on my page, I only want unique email id to get inserted into the database. For that, I have already set my emailid column as unique. But, I want that when a user tries to enter an email id which already exists within the database, the user should be redirected to the registration page.

Following is my code, but it's just not working.

```
@WebServlet({"/RegistrationServlet"})
public class RegistrationServlet extends HttpServlet
{


    Statement st = null;




  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public RegistrationServlet() {}

  UserData ud = new UserData();

  String email99 = ud.getEmail();

  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException
  {}

  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException
  {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();


    ud.setFirst_name(request.getParameter("f1"));
    ud.setLast_name(request.getParameter("l1"));
    ud.setUname(request.getParameter("uname"));
    ud.setPhone(request.getParameter("p1"));
    ud.setEmail(request.getParameter("e1"));
    ud.setUser_dob(request.getParameter("udate"));
    ud.setPassword(request.getParameter("pwd"));
    ud.setConfirm_password(request.getParameter("cpwd"));


    if (ud.getConfirm_password().equals(ud.getPassword())) {




        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");


          Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=FALSE", "root", "password");



          st = con.createStatement();

           String query1 = "select email from users";


           ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query1);

           while(rs.next()) {

           String ename = rs.getString("email");

            System.out.println("DB Email IDs:- "+ename);

            if(ename.equals(email99)) {

                response.sendRedirect("Register.jsp");
            }
            else {


                writeData();



            }


            con.close();

            rs.close();


           }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: "t's just not working" isn't really helping. In what way isn't it working? Does recognizing the duplicate fail? Does the redirect fail? Do you get exceptions?

Comment: Btw, under which circumstances do you expect `email99.equals(email99)` to return `false`? Assuming you mean `email99.equals(ename)` what happens if the case is different (a common difference could be `Email@whatever.com` vs. `email@whatever.com`)?

Comment: *"How to restrict multiple Email IDs to insert into the database?"* Only one valid possible answer.. Add a `UNIQUE` key on your column in the table... Dont do the check in the application before you insert race conditions are possible without a `UNIQUE` key meaning duplicates can still happen.

Comment: @Thomas Yes, the if condition should run and it should redirect to the Register.jsp page as I have tried entering the same email address.

Comment: @Thomas, That was a typo, I have changed it

Comment: What happens when you call `response.sendRedirect("Register.jsp");`? Did you check the server's response in the browser's dev tools?

Comment: It skips the if condition and else gets executed. The writeData() method is getting called

Comment: @Raymond I did that, but still it's not redirecting to the desired page

Comment: *"I did that, but still it's not redirecting to the desired page "* then you need to debug, more it can't help futher..Mine .jsp knowledge is very limitted, i can read it because i know Java and understood more or less what you was doing.. Mine comment about the UNIQUE key was more meant as a general warning.

Comment: Thank you Raymond. I have a Model class which is storing the user object. Above, I am just trying to match the user entered email (email99 = ud.getEmail) with ename (ename fetches the email value) and I am storing that in a string variable. So, I'm just comparing both the String values and have put them into a condition.

Comment: what is  the value of ud.getEmail() from a newly created object?

Comment: ud.getEmail stores the user's email id (What the user fills in the email column)

Comment: change your code to `if(ename.equals(ud.getEmail())) {`

Comment: I tried that as well, still the same thing

Comment: also why are you closing the connection and the result set in the while loop? which means that it closes in the first iteration.